# How to use Samsung OAuth login on Android Device?

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk

I am interested in adding an OAuth 2.0 login for Samsung Accounts on the Android device, but I can't seem to find any documentation on this. Could you please share any APIs, documentation on how to achieve this for Samsung Accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be very complicated: they should be explaining all the stuff there: [Samsung doc](http://developer.samsung.com/account) but it seems to be more or less in beta and I do not know exactly if it is even still possible to get a key. I would drop them a mail to know the status of this API :D

If you refer to this response of this [link](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=244247), they mentionned ChatON but it has been closed last year so that could be that this project has been taken down and that there will never be a stable and working Account API :( I would use Google Auth instead, which is widely used, but give a try, you never know maybe it's perfectly working!